# Remove duplicated rows from large table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have large table (~1,000,000 rows) that may contain duplicates values.

the table contain two columns (for example col a, col b) that together represent unique key, ID and last update date.

for example I can have table like:

id | a   | b      | update

1  | jon | smith  | 1/1

2  | don | smith  | 2/5

3  | bob | david  | 1/1

4  | dan | lewis  | 3/1

5  | bob | david  | 3/1

As you can see for id 3 and 5 the table contain the same values in both a and b columns.
I would like to delete the rows that contain this kind of duplication , but keep the last updated row.

For this example I will have this table after deletion:
id | a   | b      | update

1  | jon | smith  | 1/1

2  | don | smith  | 2/5

4  | dan | lewis  | 3/1

5  | bob | davis  | 3/1

(id = 3 deleted ,since I already have a=bob and b=davis in row where id=5 and the update in this row is higher then the one in the deleted row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from MyTable
where exists (
    select 1 from MyTable t2
    where MyTable.a=t2.a and MyTable.b=t2.b and MyTable.upd<t2.upd
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below one should work.

`DELETE 
 FROM     MYTABLE
 WHERE ID IN(
 SELECT   M1.ID 
 FROM     MYTABLE M1,
          MYTABLE M2
 WHERE     M1.A = M2.A
       AND M1.B = M2.B
       AND M1.ID < M2.ID);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two self-references in your WHERE clause. The first identifies rows with duplicates and the second will make sure that you're not deleting the most recent version.

```
DELETE
FROM     TestCase
WHERE    EXISTS (
   -- Where there's more than one
   SELECT   1
   FROM     TestCase AS Reference
   WHERE    TestCase.a = Reference.a
        AND TestCase.b = Reference.b
        AND TestCase.[update] <> Reference.[update]
   )
     AND TestCase.[update] <> (
   -- and this isn't the most recent
   SELECT   Max (Reference2.[update])
   FROM     TestCase AS Reference2
   WHERE    TestCase.a = Reference2.a
        AND TestCase.b = Reference2.b
   GROUP BY Reference2.a,
            Reference2.b
   )
```

Comment: one self-reference should be sufficient, because inequality of the latest update is enough to prevent a row from matching up with itself.

Comment: You're right, dasblinkenlight. And on a large table like this, the performance gain will be significant. Kudos. ;)